# To prove orthogonal projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, operator-theory

Let $W \subset V$ and $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$. Denote by $w \in W$ and $w^{\perp} \in W^{\perp}$. Let $P: V \to V$ be a (linear) operator and satisfies
       $$P^{2} = P,$$
       $$P|_{w} = id|_{w}, (i.e. P[w] = w),$$
       $$\langle P[u],v\rangle = \langle u,P[v]\rangle.$$
Prove $P[w + w^{\perp}] = w$, i.e. $P$ is an orthogonal projection operator.

Proof. I have
$$P[w + w^{\perp}]= P[w ] + P[w^{\perp}].$$
For any $w' \in W$,
$$\langle P[w^{\perp}],w'\rangle = \langle w^{\perp},P[w']\rangle = \langle w^{\perp},w'\rangle = 0.$$
...

I know I actually need to prove $P[w^{\perp}] = 0$, but I can only do this far. This is an exercise that I wrote down from my class (may not 100% accurate), but I really cannot solve it. Hope to get some help here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using matrix notation since we must have $Pw = w$ this implies that $Pv = P(w + w^\perp)= Pw + Pw^\perp = w + Pw^\perp$ together with $Pv = w$ gives us $w= w + Pw^\perp$ and therefore $Pw^\perp = 0$ as required.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you answer. But in the assumption is $P: V \to V$, not $P: V \to W$, which means that $Pv = w $ is not always valid. Do I remember it wrong or something?

Comment: @R.H Because the operator is idempotent, ie $P^2=P$ it is a projection.The only subspace stabilized by a projection is the image of the projection and that follows from the requirement that $P|_{w} = id|_{w}$.